# A Number Theory Question about Polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory

Now we have a Polynomial $P(n)$ on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It can't be wriiten as $P(n)=F(n)G(n)$ while $F(n),G(n) \neq 1$.
Is it right that for any $P(n)$, there is a $n$ such that $P(n)$ is a prime?
Is it right that for any $P(n)$, there is a $n$ such that $P(n)$ is not a square-number?

Comment: $P(n)=n^2+n+4$ is a counterexample.

Comment: This is classical. See www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/poly2.pdf

Comment: Please explain the motivation for your question. 

Do you mean $\not= \pm 1$ when you write $\not=1$? 

I assume that by "prime" you mean "positive or negative prime". 

Comment: The second part is a special case of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem;
indeed it's necessary and sufficient that $P$ is not the square of
another polynomial.  This guarantees that the $k$-th finite difference
of $\sqrt{P(n)}$ is not identically zero for any $k$.  But once
$k > \frac12 \deg(P)$, that finite difference approaches zero
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so once $m$ is large enough one of
$\sqrt{P(m+1)}$, $\sqrt{P(m+2)}$, $\sqrt{P(m+3)}$, ..., $\sqrt{P(m+k)}$
is not an integer.


Comment: Dear François Brunault, thank you, that helps me a lot. \\
Dear Goldstern, +-1. \\
Dear Noam D. Elkies, I've been showed something interesting by you, thanks.